# My IP is Blocked by Cpanel how to add my IP in Whitelist?

Tags: ip, cpanel, blacklist

How can I put my IP in whitelist that I won't face BlackList in Cpanel anymore?

I tried following way but no success, I mean still my IP is in blackList

1. In cPanel, find the "Databases" section.
2. Select "Remote MySQL".
3. Enter the IP address you wish to whitelist in the field provided.
4. Click "Add Host".

I really appreciate your advice here.
Regards

Comment: Ip blocked where?  For access to any service? For access to mysql remotely? Are Cpanel user account or WHM root?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your IP in server firewall allow list but with the cPanel access you can't do it. You will have to contact your hosting provider to add your IP in a firewall allow list.

Answer (score 0):

The steps you have mentioned are used to allow remote MySQL access on an IP address from cPanel.

If cPanel access is getting blocked then you will have to add your IP in server firewall. This can only help you if you have a static IP address.